Converting cubemaps to equirectangular panorama using the GPU
Given six quadratic cubemaps (aspect ratio 1:1, resolution 1000x1000) with a FOV of 90°, I'm trying to convert them into an equirectangular panorama (aspect ratio 2:1, resolution 4000x2000). My current approach is to calculate the spherical coordinates for each pixel of the equirectangular panorama, calculate the cartesian coordinates from the spherical coordinates, estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located, and estimate the corresponding pixel on that cube, as shown below (the letters stand for North, South, East, West, Up, Down).
def uv_pano_to_uv_cubes(u_pano, v_pano, cubemap_shape, panorama_shape):

    # Calculate the spherical coordinates from 2D image coordinates
    phi = (u_pano / panorama_shape[0] - 0.5) * np.pi
    theta = (v_pano / panorama_shape[1] + 0.25) * 2 * np.pi

    # Calculate the cartesian coordinates from the spherical coordinates
    x = np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(phi)
    z = np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located
    if abs(x) >= abs(y) and abs(x) >= abs(z):
        face = 'E' if x > 0 else 'W'
        a = z if x > 0 else -z
        b = y
        ma = abs(x)
    elif abs(y) >= abs(x) and abs(y) >= abs(z):
        face = 'D' if y > 0 else 'U'
        a = x
        b = z if y > 0 else -z
        ma = abs(y)
    else:
        face = 'S' if z > 0 else 'N'
        a = -x if z > 0 else x
        b = y
        ma = abs(z)

    # Estimate the corresponding pixel on the cube
    u_cube = int(((a / ma) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1))
    v_cube = int(((b / ma) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1))

    return face, u_cube, v_cube

If I use a Python script and do the calculations on the CPU, it takes several seconds to perform the conversion. Is there a way to do this calculation on the GPU, preferably using Python? I have read that it should be possible using OpenGL or DirectX, but I haven't found a way yet.
I have tried to improve the performance using multi-threading on the CPU, but that didn't help much. I have also tried to write an OpenGL shader, but failed.

Did you do any research into any of the many libraries available for using the GPU in Python, such as CUDA and CuPy (which seems like a good choice as you're already using Numpy)?

Using CuPy has indeed improved my performance a lot, thank you! I have included a detailed solution below.

First, I have implemented an optimized version using NumPy by calculating all uv-coordinates and faces at once instead of calculating the uv-coordinate and face for each pixel of the equirectangular panorama separately. This improved the performance by a factor of 10 on my machine.
def uv_pano_to_uv_cubes_cpu(u_pano, v_pano, cubemap_shape, panorama_shape):

    # Calculate the spherical coordinates from 2D image coordinates
    phi   = (u_pano / panorama_shape[0] * 1 - 0.5) * cp.pi
    theta = (v_pano / panorama_shape[1] * 2 + 0.5) * cp.pi

    # Calculate the cartesian coordinates from the spherical coordinates
    x = np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(phi)
    z = np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)

    # Initialize arrays for the faces and the uv-coordinates on the cubemaps
    faces   = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=np.int32)
    u_cubes = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    v_cubes = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=np.float32)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (North - South)
    condition_N_S = (abs(z) >= abs(x)) & (abs(z) >= abs(y))
    faces[condition_N_S] = np.where(z[condition_N_S] < 0, NORTH, SOUTH)
    a = y
    b = np.where(z > 0, -x, x)
    ma = abs(z)
    u_cubes[condition_N_S] = ((a[condition_N_S] / ma[condition_N_S]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_N_S] = ((b[condition_N_S] / ma[condition_N_S]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (East - West)
    condition_E_W = (abs(x) >= abs(y)) & (abs(x) >= abs(z))
    faces[condition_E_W] = np.where(x[condition_E_W] > 0, EAST, WEST)
    a = y
    b = np.where(x > 0, z, -z)
    ma = abs(x)
    u_cubes[condition_E_W] = ((a[condition_E_W] / ma[condition_E_W]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_E_W] = ((b[condition_E_W] / ma[condition_E_W]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (Up - Down)
    condition_U_D = (abs(y) >= abs(x)) & (abs(y) >= abs(z))
    faces[condition_U_D] = np.where(y[condition_U_D] < 0, UP, DOWN)
    a = np.where(y > 0, z, -z)
    b = x
    ma = abs(y)
    u_cubes[condition_U_D] = ((a[condition_U_D] / ma[condition_U_D]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_U_D] = ((b[condition_U_D] / ma[condition_U_D]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    return faces, u_cubes.astype(int), v_cubes.astype(int)

def cubes_to_panorama_cpu(cubes):

    # Initalize an empty array for the equirectangular panorama on the CPU
    if len(cubes[NORTH].shape) > 2:
        pano_shape = (int(cubes[NORTH].shape[0] * 2), int(cubes[NORTH].shape[1] * 4), cubes[NORTH].shape[2])
    else:
        pano_shape = (int(cubes[NORTH].shape[0] * 2), int(cubes[NORTH].shape[1] * 4))
    pano = np.zeros(pano_shape, dtype=cp.uint8)

    # Initalize arrays for the indices of the panorama
    u_pano, v_pano = np.meshgrid(np.arange(pano_shape[0]), np.arange(pano_shape[1]), indexing='ij')

    # Calculate all corresponding indices on the cubemaps
    faces, u_cubes, v_cubes = Panorama.uv_pano_to_uv_cubes_cpu(u_pano, v_pano, cubes[NORTH].shape, pano_shape)

    # Write the corresponding pixels to the panorama
    for face in range(6):
        pano[faces == face] = cubes[face][u_cubes[faces == face], v_cubes[faces == face]]

    return pano

Second, I replaced all NumPy functions with CuPy functions. This further improved the performance by another factor of 3 on my machine.
def uv_pano_to_uv_cubes_gpu(u_pano, v_pano, cubemap_shape, panorama_shape):

    # Calculate the spherical coordinates from 2D image coordinates
    phi   = (u_pano / panorama_shape[0] * 1 - 0.5) * cp.pi
    theta = (v_pano / panorama_shape[1] * 2 + 0.5) * cp.pi

    # Calculate the cartesian coordinates from the spherical coordinates
    x = cp.cos(phi) * cp.cos(theta)
    y = cp.sin(phi)
    z = cp.cos(phi) * cp.sin(theta)

    # Initialize arrays for the faces and the uv-coordinates on the cubemaps
    faces   = cp.empty(x.shape, dtype=cp.int32)
    u_cubes = cp.empty(x.shape, dtype=cp.float32)
    v_cubes = cp.empty(x.shape, dtype=cp.float32)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (North - South)
    condition_N_S = (abs(z) >= abs(x)) & (abs(z) >= abs(y))
    faces[condition_N_S] = cp.where(z[condition_N_S] < 0, NORTH, SOUTH)
    a = y
    b = cp.where(z > 0, -x, x)
    ma = abs(z)
    u_cubes[condition_N_S] = ((a[condition_N_S] / ma[condition_N_S]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_N_S] = ((b[condition_N_S] / ma[condition_N_S]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (East - West)
    condition_E_W = (abs(x) >= abs(y)) & (abs(x) >= abs(z))
    faces[condition_E_W] = cp.where(x[condition_E_W] > 0, EAST, WEST)
    a = y
    b = cp.where(x > 0, z, -z)
    ma = abs(x)
    u_cubes[condition_E_W] = ((a[condition_E_W] / ma[condition_E_W]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_E_W] = ((b[condition_E_W] / ma[condition_E_W]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    # Estimate on which cubemap the pixel is located (Up - Down)
    condition_U_D = (abs(y) >= abs(x)) & (abs(y) >= abs(z))
    faces[condition_U_D] = cp.where(y[condition_U_D] < 0, UP, DOWN)
    a = cp.where(y > 0, z, -z)
    b = x
    ma = abs(y)
    u_cubes[condition_U_D] = ((a[condition_U_D] / ma[condition_U_D]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[0] - 1)
    v_cubes[condition_U_D] = ((b[condition_U_D] / ma[condition_U_D]) + 1.0) * 0.5 * (cubemap_shape[1] - 1)

    return faces, u_cubes.astype(int), v_cubes.astype(int)

def cubes_to_panorama_gpu(cubes):

    # Initalize an empty array for the equirectangular panorama on the GPU
    if len(cubes[NORTH].shape) > 2:
        pano_shape = (int(cubes[NORTH].shape[0] * 2), int(cubes[NORTH].shape[1] * 4), cubes[NORTH].shape[2])
    else:
        pano_shape = (int(cubes[NORTH].shape[0] * 2), int(cubes[NORTH].shape[1] * 4))
    pano = cp.zeros(pano_shape, dtype=cp.uint8)

    # Move the cubemaps to the GPU
    cubes[NORTH] = cp.asarray(cubes[NORTH])
    cubes[SOUTH] = cp.asarray(cubes[SOUTH])
    cubes[EAST]  = cp.asarray(cubes[EAST])
    cubes[WEST]  = cp.asarray(cubes[WEST])
    cubes[UP]    = cp.asarray(cubes[UP])
    cubes[DOWN]  = cp.asarray(cubes[DOWN])

    # Initalize arrays for the indices of the panorama
    u_pano, v_pano = cp.meshgrid(cp.arange(pano_shape[0]), cp.arange(pano_shape[1]), indexing='ij')

    # Calculate all corresponding indices on the cubemaps
    faces, u_cubes, v_cubes = Panorama.uv_pano_to_uv_cubes_gpu(u_pano, v_pano, cubes[NORTH].shape, pano_shape)

    # Write the corresponding pixels to the panorama
    for face in range(6):
        pano[faces == face] = cubes[face][u_cubes[faces == face], v_cubes[faces == face]]

    # Move the panorama to the CPU
    pano = cp.asnumpy(pano)

    return pano

Note that the signs and assignment of calculations may vary depending on the capture process and the orientation of the cubemaps.
